# R: How to select columns with dplyr matches?

Tags: r, regex, select, dplyr, string-matching

I'm a beginner in using regex and `dplyr::matches()` so this is probably a silly question:

How to select columns with leading zero digits in the name **using `dplyr::matches()`**?

An example data:

```
d <- data.frame(
    var_001 = c( 1, 2, 3 ),
    var_012 = c( 4, 5, 6 ),
    var_001_b = c( 11, 22, 33 ),
    var = c( 7, 8, 9 )
)
```

The pattern I've built:

```
pattern <- 'var_[0*\\d+]{3}$'
```

If I use `str_match()`, I'm able to detect the correct names:

```
str_match( names( d ), pattern )

#>      [,1]     
#> [1,] "var_001"
#> [2,] "var_012"
#> [3,] NA       
#> [4,] NA
```

However, using `matches()` in `select()` does not return any columns:

```
d %>%
    select( matches( pattern ) )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 0
```

Comment: You need to have `perl = TRUE`. Try `d %>% select(matches('var_[0*\\d+]{3}$', perl = T))`

Comment: Or `d %>% select(matches('var_\\d+{3}$'))`.

Comment: Thanks @benson23 and @r2evans! So, these are two different flavors of regex (Perl compatible and the other), I guess? I'll have to do some more studying (e.g. why does the original pattern work with `str_match()` but not with `matches()`, and how do I separate the different flavors).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
d %>% 
  select(matches("^var_0"))
```

Another way:

```
d %>% 
  select(starts_with("var_0" ))
```